# What does トラックなど１２台の車 mean?

Tags: grammar, word-order, particle-など

I've been trying to figure this text out in NHK news easy:
http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/k10010447431000/k10010447431000.html

There is a part when it says: トラックなど１２台の車がぶつかる事故がありました。
I couldn't understand this トラックなど１２台の車 exactly, the order of the words are confusing me I think. I'm reading "truck 12 cars", and I don't know what this など is doing. I think the overall meaning is "one truck and twelve cars", but I want to know exactly which role each word is playing. Could someone explain this part to me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

「など」means like "etc." or "and so on".  Here, 車 isn't necessarily "cars", but "vehicles".  So overall, it means "There was an accident involving 12 vehicles (trucks included)."  Or you could more easily say "A 12-car pileup"; in this case—even in English—you would know that "12-car" is not just limited to actual "cars", but vehicles.

Comment: Thanks. It makes more sense now. I still don't understand what の is doing there though. Also, is １２台 related to トラックな or 車?

Comment: 台 is the counter used for vehicles and other "machines".  So 12台の車 is simply "12 vehicles".

Comment: But wouldn't just 12台車 be correct? What is this の doing? Also, I was trying to understand what is related to what, what's the hierarchy, like is it:
" ( トラックなど１２台 ) の 車 " ? that is, 車 is specifying トラックなど１２台,
or:
" トラックなど (１２台の車 )  " ? that is, トラックなど is specifying １２台の車 ?

Comment: No,  just 12台車 would be incorrect. It needs の.   ( トラックなど１２台 ) の 車 is correct way to analyze it. Think of it like, vehicles - including trucks, 12 of them in total - were involved in the accident.